# Changing the path after entering WooCommerce my-account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**The user panel in WooCommerce** is very simple, and to edit it, you need to change a lot of **WooCommerce files**, which is very time-consuming, and worst of all, after **updating WooCommerce**, you need to edit the files according to the new changes. (**copy WooCommerce files in the template path and edit them**).

For this reason, I want to redirect the user to my user panel instead of going to the default WooCommerce user panel after entering the **my-account** page.

I have already used the following code to redirect the WooCommerce store page:

```
function wpc_shop_url_redirect() {
  if( is_shop() ){
      wp_redirect( home_url( '/shoptest' ) );
      exit();
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpc_shop_url_redirect' );
```

Now I want to create the same redirection for WooCommerce user panel.

---

**Edite:**

I found this code snippet to redirect the user to my custom panel page after successful login.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'woo_login_redirect');
function woo_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
return 'AccountTest'; 
}
```

This code correctly redirects the user to the page I want.

The main problem of this code is that it redirects the user to the desired page only once and only after the successful login, but the next time it is redirected to the WooCommerce default page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect the user to your custom user panel instead of the default WooCommerce user panel after entering the "my-account" page, you can use a similar approach as the one you used for redirecting the WooCommerce store page. Here's the modified code to achieve this:

```
function custom_redirect_to_user_panel() {
    if (is_account_page()) {
        // Replace 'custom-user-panel-url' with the URL of your custom user panel
        wp_redirect('custom-user-panel-url');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_redirect_to_user_panel');
```

Comment: **Hello**. I tested your code and encountered this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument ... C:\xampp\htdocs\site\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 308` This error was displayed when I wanted to enter the WooCommerce login page (**my-account**). I want the login page to load well and after successful login to my desired account page.

Comment: I used your code in these modes: first mode: pasting **AccountTest** - second mode: pasting `http://localhost/site/AccountTest` - third mode: `wp_redirect( home_url( '/AccountTest' ) );` . But in all three cases, the above error appeared.

Comment: I got it the issue because the function name is wrong in action hook. Apologies For that. 
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_accountto_custom_redirect');

Comment: I also tested this code. But as soon as I refreshed my template home page I got the same error again. I edited my question, please take a look.